# checking file content in Make

Tags: makefile

I am doing some data validation. Basically, I have a list of files and I want to make sure they are consistent. For a file to be consistent, they need to match the number of occurences.

```
grep -c ValidId file.????.txt
wc -l < output.????.txt
```

If they both match, I would like to create a done file so I don't have to recheck again. This will be a routine in my Makefile for data validation.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want one file containing a list of the file-pairs that are consistent? Or that for each consistent file-pair (`file.foo.txt`, `output.foo.txt`) you want such a file (`foo.done`)?

Comment: I am doing a validation check. It takes a long time to generate file.foo.txt. output.foo.txt is easy to generate. I want to compare if file.foo.txt has the same number of "ValidId". If so, then I know my results are good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern match `%` can be used in multiple dependencies in the rule. One can use that to keep track of the consistent files, so that running make and correcting errors would be checking only the not-yet-consistent files:

```
FILES=$(wildcard file.????.txt)
RES_FILES=$(FILES:file.%=.result.%)

all: $(RES_FILES)

.result.%.txt: file.%.txt output.%.txt
    if [ `grep -c ValidId < file.$*.txt` -eq \
         `wc -l < output.$*.txt` ]; then \
       touch $@ ; \
    fi

clean:
    @rm -f $(RES_FILES)
```